# Merge dicts and create list if duplicate keys

Tags: python

I have two dicts in Python which I want to merge. Some of the keys exists in both dicts and I would like them to be in a list in the new dict. Like this:

```
A = {'item1': 'val1', 'item2': 'val2'}
B = {'item2': 'val3', 'item3': 'val4'}
```

Should result in this:

```
{'item1': 'val1', 'item2': ['val2', 'val3'], 'item3': 'val4'}
```

How do I do that?

Comment: do you want lists only if there were duplicate keys?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to keep the structure of the new dict consistent as in `{'item1': ['val1'], 'item2': ['val2', 'val3'], 'item3': ['val4']}`? Otherwise, you'd have to wrestle with `isinstance()` and such each time you're accessing the value(s) of the dict, not knowing whether they will be strings or lists...

Comment: Ok, it might be a better solution to always have lists as values, so, how do i solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some clear code to achieve on efficient way.

```
import collections

newMap = collections.defaultdict(list)

for key, value in A.iteritems():
    newMap[key].append(value)
```

Comment: you need to loop over B to achieve the desire result